# "Friedrichs extension Laplacian" vs "Weak Laplacian" and fractional powers

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Take $\Omega$ to be a bounded domain and consider Neumann BCs.

In some works, I see that a Laplacian $(-\Delta_D)^{\frac 12}$ is defined as an operator with domain $H^1(\Omega)$, and in other works, another operator is defined as $(-\Delta_W)^{\frac 12}\colon H^{\frac 12}(\Omega) \to H^{\frac 12}(\Omega)^*$.

I think the first definition is a "Friedrichs extension Laplacian" and the second is what I would call a "weak Laplacian", and I prefer the second infinitely since it is better in PDE theory. For example, I would define the Laplacian as: $-\Delta \colon H^1(\Omega) \to H^1(\Omega)^*$, $\langle -\Delta u, v \rangle = \int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla v.$

My understanding is, in the work of Shubin and Seeley etc, the second is used, is this correct? When people talk that the square root of Laplaian is a pseduodifferential operator, isn't the weak version what they mean, in terms of domain and range and function spaces? I am just a bit confused about these two definitions and the fact in literature the same notations are used.

Comment: I believe this question really belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/. As for the actual question, I suspect you might be confusing the *quadratic form* $u\mapsto \int |\nabla u|^2$ on $H^1$ with the operator itself (this is the form corresponding to the Neumann Laplacian [= operator], but it's not the same object, and $H^1$ is not the domain of the operator).